# MI function definition in one base class not sufficient for virtual function of another base class

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

I have a derived class inheriting from both an interface and a base class. The interface defines a virtual function `GetId`, which is implemented in the other base class.

```
class ITestClient
{
  public:
    virtual int GetId() = 0;
};

class BaseClient
{
  public:
    int GetId();
}

int BaseClient::GetId()
{
  return 10;
}

class TestClient : public ITestClient, public BaseClient {
};
```

I get `unimplemented pure virtual method 'GetId'`. So I could do this to fix the compile error...

```
class TestClient : public ITestClient, public BaseClient {
  int GetId()
  {
    return BaseClient::GetId();
  }
};
```

Why isn't the base class `BaseClient`'s concrete function definition of `GetId` sufficient as an implementation of the interface's virtual function?

Comment: Why not just have `BaseClient` derive from `ITestClient`?

Comment: Are you asking why the language is defined that way? Or do you think there is a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Imagine the compiler worked the way you expect. What should happen if you derive from yet another class, `Unrelated`, that also happens to have a method named `GetId()` (which was not intended to have anything to do with `ITestClient`; say it's coming from a third-party library)? Worse still, imagine that `Unrelated` didn't originally have `GetId()` method, and your program worked fine; but later the third-party authors added a private `GetId()` for their own reasons. C++ has enough problems with [fragile base classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) as is.

Comment: Or consider this: `class Base { virtual int GetId() { return 42; } }; class Unrelated {}; class Derived : public Base, public Unrelated {};` So far so good: `Derived d; d.GetId();` would return 42. Now, someone adds `private: int GetId() { return -1; }` to `Unrelated`. What should happen, in your ideal world? Should it be an error? Should `Unrelated::GetId()` be ignored? Or should `d.GetId()` silently change meaning and start returning -1 where before it returned 42?

Comment: @RSahu yeah, I was confused about c++ multiple inheritance and wondering why the language is defined this way

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that makes sense thanks. I had a wrong assumption about inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. 
`BaseClient` *is-not-A* `ITestClient` (*is-A* relationship is the inheritance property required). So the definition in `BaseClient` cannot be an implementation of that interface function.

The son of a friend of yours won't start looking like you just because you take him along in your car, your own son however will. That's the equivalent relation.

Comment: I see. I figured that since BaseClient and ITestClient are all "in the same car" together, the compiler could get them to get along with each other.

Comment: In Java the equivalent code works exactly how the asker thinks it should. So the answer needs to be specific to C++.

Comment: Sure, as the code is C++ and his tags are C++/C++11 though, I saw no reason to think the question was unrelated to C++.